# How to stop hammer.js from conflicting with the normal scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, hammer.js

im using hammer.js to detect drags and swipes.

Thats the code:

```
var element = document.getElementById('pinwall-grid');
                    var hammertime = Hammer(element).on("drag", function (event) {
                        direction = event.gesture.direction;
                        if (direction == 'left') {

                            var $meN = $('.pinwall-grid .ctrl a.next');

                            if (!$meN.hasClass("nextD")) {
                                $meN.trigger('click');
                            }

                            console.log('left');


                        } else if (direction == 'right') {

                                var $meP = $('.pinwall-grid .ctrl a.prev');

                                if (!$meP.hasClass("prevD")) {
                                    $meP.trigger('click');
                                }

                                console.log('right');
                            }

                    event.gesture.stopDetect();
                });
```

If you swipe up and down on mobile and your finger is on the div i'm targeting using hammer.js, it dosnt scroll down or up the viewport.

Check http://86.62.248.112/en/ on mobile using chrome to see what im talking about, out your finger on the Latest News div and swipe.

How can i fix that?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

If someone is facing the same issue,

first you need to update your version of hammer.js and then add `touch-action:pan-y` to the div in question.